# MSBuild failing to build referenced projects when upgrading to VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, web

I have recently upgraded my .Net 3.5 solution containing some C# code projects and a ASP.net web site project to VS2010 (from VS2008). It is building and running fine inside VS, but I get some problems when trying to build it on my server with MSBuild 4.0 via TeamCity. It seems like the projects that are referenced from the web site are not built. This was all working fine before I upgraded to VS2010, MSbuild 4.0 and Windows SDK 7.1.

Inside the msbuild script that I use to build from teamcity I have defined project references for the web site like this:

```
  <ProjectReference Include="..\src\trunk\DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj">
     <Project>{C43242F4-7286-4BEC-9A27-001D6FC14860}</Project>
     <Name>DataAccess</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
```

When I try to run the build script I get an error message saying that it could not find the dll file when trying to copy it from the bin folder of the referenced project into the bin folder of the web site. This is happening because the referenced projects are in fact never built at all (No bin folder exists in the project dir).

Does anyone have a clue what may cause this? I am not very experienced with MSbuild, so I may have overlooked some important stuff. Is it not so that MSbuild will automatically try to build the referenced projects if no project output is existing?

Will be thankful for any help!

Comment: Can you post the content of your csproj files? Only the beginning, until the reference part begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need some more info to guide you on this, but off the top of my head try adding

```
/toolsversion:3.5
```

to your msbuild call.

Comment: Tried setting toolsversion to 3.5, but then I get another crash in my build script because this one is not supported by the 3.5 tools: <TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\</TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin>. I found out that I needed to set this to make MSBuild use the correct version of aspnet_merge.exe. If I do not have that specified it will run the FX .Net 4.0 version of aspnet_merge.exe instead..

Comment: I managed to remove the need for setting TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryBin in my script, and then I got to run the project using Toolsversion 3.5. And guess what: It worked! Thanks a bunch! I am however curious to why toolsversion 4.0 behaved in such a way. Any idea on that?

Comment: Not yet. I'm still in the process of digging into the differences, mainly because of similar troubles with silverlight projects. It's just that I know for now that there are several differences (maybe even the odd bug) in the 4.0 Tools version, so I thought using 3.5 on a 3.5 project might help to restore the original behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found another post on this website describing your exact same problem. I also ran into this same problem too.
This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx) on the MSDN Website describes the problem and the work-around. Basically it's a limitation of solution files which are not in an MSBuild format, but just a fancy text file. And the real thing is, that the dependencies need to be specified in the project files them selves not the solution file. ahhh... just read the link it explains it a hundred times better than my answer here.